# Auth POST request with Axios directed to wrong http address and returning 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post, axios

I am having trouble with the auth for my app. When sending a POST request to from the client with information from a form in the signup component, I receive the following error in my console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)
```

I know that the correct address to direct my POST request to would be 'localhost:5005', which is where my server is running. But when I don't hard code this in the 'services/auth.js' on the client side, it defaults to 'localhost:3000' and throws the error. But I can't workout where this is defined / where I need to change it.

If I hard code the target of the POST request to 'http://localhost:5005/api/auth/signup', the code runs and the new user entries are made in the database.

FYI The code below throws the 404 error, as above.

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if I have omitted any important information.

## client/src/services/auth.js

````
```
import axios from 'axios';

const signup = (email, password, firstname, lastname) => {
  return axios
    .post('/api/auth/signup', { email, password, firstname, lastname})
    .then(response => {
      // console.log(response)
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // console.log(err)
      return err.response.data;
    });
};

const login = (email, password) => {
  return axios
    .post('/api/auth/login', { email, password })
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err.response.data;
    });
};

const logout = () => {
  return axios
    .delete('/api/auth/logout')
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err.response.data;
    });
};

export { signup, login, logout };
```
````

## client/src/components/Signup.js

````
```
    import { React, useState } from 'react'
import { signup } from '../services/auth'

function useInput(initialValue){
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  
  function handleChange(event){
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return [value,handleChange]
}

export default function Signup(props) {

  const [email, setEmail] = useInput('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useInput('');
  const [firstname, setFirstname] = useInput('');
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useInput('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('email:', email, 'password:', password, 'firstname:', firstname, 'lastname:', lastname)
    signup(email, password, firstname, lastname).then(data => {
      if (data.message) {
        // console.log(data.message);
        setMessage(data.message);
        // setEmail('');
        // setPassword('');
        // setFirstname('');
        // setLastname('')
      } else {
        setUser(data)
        console.log(user)
        props.history.push('/dashboard');
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <h1>User signup</h1>
    <div class='signupForm'>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <label>Email</label>
        <input 
          type='text'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={setEmail}
          id='email'
        />

        <label>Password</label>
        <input 
          type='password'
          name='password'
          value={password}
          onChange={setPassword}
          id='password'
        />

        <label>Firstname</label>
        <input 
          type='text'
          name='firstname'
          value={firstname}
          onChange={setFirstname}
          id='firstname'
        />

        <label>Lastname</label>
        <input 
          type='text'
          name='lastname'
          value={lastname}
          onChange={setLastname}
          id='lastname'
        />
        
{message && (
<alert variant='danger'>{message}</alert>
)}

<button type='submit'>Signup</button>
</form>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

```
````

### (server) routes/auth-routes.js

````
```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/User.model');

const router = express.Router();

// Signup route
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const {
    email, password, firstname, lastname,
  } = req.body;

  if (!password || password.length < 8) {
    return res
      .status(400)
      .json({ message: 'Your password must be 8 char. min.' });
  }
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Your email cannot be empty' });
  }

  // check if username exists in database -> show message
  User.findOne({ email })
    .then((found) => {
      if (found) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: 'This email is already taken' });
      }

      // hash the password, create the user and send the user to the client
      const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
      const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);

      return User.create({
        email, password: hash, firstname, lastname,
      }).then(
        (dbUser) => {
          // login with passport:
          req.login(dbUser, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              return res
                .status(500)
                .json({ message: 'Error while attempting to login' });
            }
            return res.status(200).json(dbUser);
          });
        },
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.json(err);
    });
});

// Login route
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error while authenticating' });
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Wrong credentials' });
    }
    req.login(user, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: 'Error while attempting to login' });
      }
      return res.json(user);
    });
  })(req, res);
});

// Delete user route
router.delete('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.json({ message: 'Successful logout' });
});

// returns the logged in user
router.get('/loggedin', (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.user);
});

// when login is successful, retrieve user info
router.get('/login/success', (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'user has successfully authenticated',
      user: req.user,
      cookies: req.cookies,
    });
  }
});

// auth with google
router.get(
  '/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    ],
  }),
);
router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/private-page',
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    failureRedirect: '/login', // here you would redirect to the login page using traditional login approach
  }),
);

module.exports = router;
```
````

## app.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const cors = require('cors');

// ℹ️ Gets access to environment variables/settings
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
require('dotenv/config');

// ℹ️ Connects to the database
require('./db');

// Handles http requests (express is node js framework)
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express

const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// ℹ️ This function is getting exported from the config folder. It runs most middlewares
require('./config')(app);

app.use(
  cors({
    // this could be multiple domains/origins, but we will allow just our React app
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  }),
);

// session configuration

const session = require('express-session');

// session store using mongo
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

const mongoose = require('./db/index');

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    // Forces the session to be saved back to the session store,
    // even if the session was never modified during the request.
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({
      // mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017',
    }),
  }),
);
// end of session configuration

// passport configuration

const User = require('./models/User.model');

// we serialize only the `_id` field of the user to keep the information stored minimum
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
  done(null, user._id);
});

// when we need the information for the user, the deserializeUser function is called with
// the id that we previously serialized to fetch the user from the database
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id)
    .then((dbUser) => {
      done(null, dbUser);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET,
      callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      // to see the structure of the data in received response:
      console.log('Google account details:', profile);

      User.findOne({ googleID: profile.id })
        .then((user) => {
          if (user) {
            done(null, user);
            return;
          }

          User.create({ googleID: profile.id })
            .then((newUser) => {
              done(null, newUser);
            })
            .catch((err) => done(err)); // closes User.create()
        })
        .catch((err) => done(err)); // closes User.findOne()
    },
  ),
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    // login
    User.findOne({ username })
      .then((userFromDB) => {
        if (userFromDB === null) {
          // there is no user with this username
          done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong Credentials' });
        } else if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, userFromDB.password)) {
          // the password is not matching
          done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong Credentials' });
        } else {
          // the userFromDB should now be logged in
          done(null, userFromDB);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }),

);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// end of passport

//  Start handling routes here
// Contrary to the views version, all routes are controled from the routes/index.js
const index = require('./routes');

app.use('/api', index);

const auth = require('./routes/auth-routes');

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

// Allows access to the API from different domains/origins BEFORE session
app.use(
  cors({
    // this could be multiple domains/origins, but we will allow just our React app
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  }),
);

//  Start handling routes here
// Contrary to the views version, all routes are controled from the routes/index.js

// This could be a conflict with line 104, so I commented it out. We can reinstate
// const allRoutes = require('./routes');
// app.use('/api', allRoutes);

const admin = require('./routes/admin');

app.use('/api', admin);

// ❗ To handle errors. Routes that don't exist or errors that you handle in specific routes
require('./error-handling')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I can't workout where this is defined / where I need to change it.

That's where your frontend is running, and you are using relative urls.  You probably just want to do:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5005';
```

Comment: Thanks, Dave. Where should I add the snippet you suggest?

Comment: I'd add it to whatever your entrypoint is for your react app

Comment: Thank you @dave your solution worked for me when I added the code in my index.js

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
return axios
    .post('/api/auth/signup'
```

it means you are having an endpoint running on same server as your frontend i.e localhost:3000 in your case, but in your case you don't have an endpoint on frontend server.